Submitting a paper to a journal and then the system breaks
I've submited a paper to a journal and was able to see the peer review process of the submited paper on the system of the journal. However, after some time it looks like the system has broken! If I type the webpage of the journal or try to enter the system from where I want to see how the peer review process is going, I get the following mesage on the screen:
"Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2"."
It's been more than a month like this. I've written an email to the editor of the journal about the issue, but I didn't get any reply.
What should I do in this case?

was this an established, reputable journal?

@Sursula I can say it didn't looked like a predatory journal. It's scope was narrow and it was registered in relevant databases.

I'm not familiar with this error message, but assuming it's not a problem on your end, then see if you can reach the journal's publisher who should be the ultimate authority to resolve technical issues like this one. One month is a long time when the error is disabling your website, they should do better.

In fact its publishers web page that shows the error. Here is it's web page: https://www.m-sciences.com (if this information can help).

@Emo The publisher might be dead then. Presumably the journal (if it's still alive) will be transferred to another publisher. Would have to wait for a response from the journal's editors to know; in the meantime probably submit elsewhere.
